# 3 Column responsive layout has a gap when resizing

Tags: html, css

Currently I am having problems designing a responsive layout using 3 columns. Firstly I want them aligned in adjacent columns, which I have achieved with % widths and floating them to the left. When the page shrinks, I want the 1st and 3rd column to appear above and below each other respectively with the 2nd column to the right of both of them. Here's what I want them to look like:

### Normal layout

[image: Desktop Layout]

### Wanted layout when resized

[image: Wanted layout for smaller device]

### Current layout when resized

The problem is that when I resize the page (so using the css which resizes the columns' % widths), the 3rd column does move to the left, but it appears below the end of the 2nd column:

[image: Current layout]

Below is a simplified example of the **html** I'm using:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="mid"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

And the **css**, n.b. the heights given are only examples and will change dynamically in the actual site:

```
.left {
    height: 10em;
    background-color: red;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}
.mid {
    height: 20em;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    height: 5em;
    background-color: green;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .left {
        width: 30%;
    }
    .right {
        width: 30%;
    }

}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle of the above in action](https://jsfiddle.net/MykonBlu/phbpaktw/1/)

### Other attempts

I can tell what the problem is, however I don't know what the solution is. Reordering the html so that the third column is in between the others and floating the column right works as desired for the large layout and then for the smaller layout I have tried floating the third column to the left and using `clear:both`, however the 2nd column is below the 1st as you can see in [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/MykonBlu/h0j4eLL0/).

I could achieve the desired effect if I set the positioning of the 3rd column, e.g. `position:relative;top:-200px`, however this seems like an inaccurate approach.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in pure CSS/HTML

Comment: @the_critic it seems it is thanks to the answers given.

Comment: Sorry I thought you would be looking at a dynamic grid with variable elements, not just the 3 you have shown there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phbpaktw/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="mid"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.mid {
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 }
.right {
 float: left;
 clear:left;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it answers and tells me how to use this for my actual case (which has a header div above the columns). By wrapping the 3 columns in a div which has relative positioning, it works perfectly, with the header staying above.

Comment: To work this code you have to set position:relative for more reference: https://jsfiddle.net/phbpaktw/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to use `flex` layout and can fix the height of the group, then...

... changing the order of child `div`s in your media-query along with a change in `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` will do the trick. Fix the height of the wrapper to be as large as the highest child `div`.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/h0j4eLL0/2/**

**Snippet:**

```css
.wrap { display: flex; }
.left {
  height: 10em; width: 15%;
  background-color: red;
}
.mid {
  height: 20em; width: 70%;
  background-color: blue; 
}
.right {
  height: 5em; width: 15%;
  background-color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .wrap { flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; height: 20em; } 
  .left { width: 30%; order: 1; }
  .mid { width: 70%; order: 3; }
  .right { width: 30%; order: 2; }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been meaning to learn about using `flex` layouts for a while. Thank you for this clear and concise answer explaining how to use this for my situation. If I could accept multiple answers, I would, however I chose Jagdish's as it uses my original css. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, just one question, if the middle column is dynamic in size, is there a different approach in order to keep this working? (without using js)

Answer (score 0):

I am sending the css and output image, this css will definitely help you ..
**the css code is**

```css
body
{
background-color: #efefef;
}

.layout
{
 background-color: #006969;
 width: 100%;
 min-height:300px;
}

.layout .left{
width: 30%;
background-color: #696900;

float: left;
}
.layout .left .uppanel
{
 background-color: #efefefe; 
 height:150px;
 float: top;
}
.layout .left .downpanel
{
 background-color: #ffffff; 
 height:150px;
 float: bottom;
}
.layout .right{
width: 70%;
background-color: #cccccc;
height:300px;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="layout">
 
  <div class="left">
    <div class="uppanel">
     Left Panel - Up div
    </div>
    <div class="downpanel">
     Left Panel - down div
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   Right Panel
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This would not keep the layout I want for larger pages ( > 500px in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I would use absolute positioning. If you chnage your css like this:

```
.left {
  height: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}
.mid {
  height: 20em;
  left:15%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  height: 5em;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .left {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .mid {
    width: 70%;
    left:30%;
  }
  .right {
    width: 30%;
    left:0;
    right:auto;
    top:10em;
  }

}
```

This is just an example how it works just for your example. In your code i would use Javascript to find out the top / right and left positioning.

You can use the resize event for that.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // Do Positioning Stuff
};
```

This is the way I would do this.

Comment: Oh i just saw it now that Jagdish Parmar has the better answere didnt saw it before.

Answer (score -1):

add  **margin-top: -140px;** to the **.right** in **@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)**

or

You can add

```
.right{
position:relative;
bottom:140px;}
```

in media query code for 500px

Comment: It seems like this approach is very inaccurate and wouldn't work should the 1st column have a greater height (note that in the example I've given, the sizes are only examples and the height may change). Upon increasing the size, the columns would overlap.

Comment: It still wouldn't work as I've described. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phbpaktw/3/) using your solution, with a large height for the 1st column.

Comment: your approach is amateurish in todays world of responsve web design best practices, thats all. There's a more "adaptive" way to achieve the desired result. Using hard set margins should be the last resort option

Comment: but putting bottom:160px in fiddle is giving me solution as u want but if you use in your code please adjust it as you want because i made this html file and there is bottom:140px is perfect.

Comment: just because you can do something and it works doesnt make it right - the mail system works but that doesnt mean we shouldnt be using email

Comment: can you please explain me why its wrong? what will happen if it use? because I am beginner.